# Is there a way to get the database sqlException/Error when debugging on browsers to create appropriate catch error message?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008, error-handling

Is there a way to get a database `SQLException` when debugging on browsers?
Say for example, primary key violations (duplicating PK when adding records)?

I'm using VS 2008, and SQL Server 2005 if it matters.

Comment: I think you need to be asking yourself the question "why would I be attempting to duplicate primary keys?". By definition, you shouldn't be. That's why they are called primary. Use a staging table...

Comment: sorry for my question, newbie here.
@mitch my table gets its primary key from users(student's id number) and my code is not the kind to 'generate/increment PK when adding records'. i'm just trying to think of every possibilities, and moreover it's just an example. please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command on sql server:

```
RAISERROR('Here comes the exception text', 16,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Code**

```
Set NOCOUNT ON
Set XACT_ABORT ON

Begin Try
  ...Your SQL Code
End Try

Begin Catch
   Rollback Tran
   Select Error_Number() as No, Error_Message() as Message
End Catch
```

---

**Page Level Error**

```
protected override void OnError(EventArgs e)
{
    Exception CurrentException = Server.GetLastError();
    string ErrorDetails = CurrentException.ToString();
    // this could also be a string[] if you prefer
    var script = string.Format("foo({0});", ErrorDetails);
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "call", script, true);
    base.OnError(e);
}
```

---

**Application Level Error**

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Exception CurrentException = Server.GetLastError();
     string ErrorDetails = CurrentException.ToString();
     // this could also be a string[] if you prefer
     var script = string.Format("foo({0});", ErrorDetails);
     ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "call", script, true);
     base.OnError(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use System.Web.HttpContext to output a JavaScript alert message box.

You put the System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand in a try catch, and in the catch you output Exception as a JavaScript alert (you need to escape the message for special characters and quotes to be handled correctly.

Here my method (VB.NET)

```
Public Shared Sub Show(ByRef objMessage As Object, Optional ByRef strTitle As String = Nothing)
    Dim strMessage As String = CStr(objMessage)
    Dim pgCallingPage As Page = TryCast(HttpContext.Current.Handler, Page)
    If pgCallingPage IsNot Nothing Then
        strMessage = Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.escape(strMessage) ' Reference Microsoft.JScript.dll in the project reference
        strMessage = "<script type=""text/javascript"" language=""javascript"">alert(unescape(""" + strMessage + """));</script>"
        pgCallingPage.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(pgCallingPage.GetType(), System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), strMessage, False)
    End If
End Sub
```

Here a C# conversion:

```
public static void Show(object objMessage, string strTitle = null)
{
    string strMessage = Convert.ToString(objMessage);
    Page pgCallingPage = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
    if (pgCallingPage != null) {
        strMessage = Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.escape(strMessage);
        // Reference Microsoft.JScript.dll in the project reference
        strMessage = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\">alert(unescape(\"" + strMessage + "\"));</script>";
        pgCallingPage.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(pgCallingPage.GetType(), System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), strMessage, false);
    }
}
```

If you don't like alert message boxes (because one cannot copy paste), I suggest you just output a new line of text (will be on top of document):

```
Public Shared Sub WriteLine(ByRef objMessage As Object)
    Dim strMessage As String = CStr(objMessage)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<br/><p style=""font-family: Verdana, Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; font-color: #FF0000; font-size: 10mm;"">" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(strMessage) + "</p><br/>")
End Sub 


public static void WriteLine(object objMessage)
{
    string strMessage = Convert.ToString(objMessage);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<br/><p style=\"font-family: Verdana, Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; font-color: #FF0000; font-size: 10mm;\">" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(strMessage) + "</p><br/>");
}
```